# Compile Qt using g++

Tags: qt, g++

I'm trying to compile a simple Qt program using g++ but I don't know how to link the libraries/headers properly and which flags to use. I can do it fine with qmake and make but I'd really like to be able to do this by only using g++.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: ... but why ???

Answer (score 1):

Do it once with `qmake` and `make`. If you did not use `CONFIG += silent`, then `make` will show you which commands it is running.

Also you have to keep in mind that you may have to run `moc` on some header files (those containing `Q_OBJECT`) to generate .cpp files that you will then need to compile.

The exact flags you need to pass to g++ depends on your system and Qt install: is Qt in your PATH ? Where is it installed ? Which Qt libraries are you using ? etc.